# Смена скринов WPF форме

Tags: wpf, c#

Добрый день! 
Вопрос такого характера есть WPF форма на которпой есть TabControl  на последнем табе есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую должно происходить сдеующее: В той же форме должен появиться новый скриин без TabControl-а. Как сделать смену скринов*? Буду рад любым советам и на ставлениям)

Answer (score 3):

Есть тысяча разных способов, разной степени концептуальности.

Например, по-простому: положите контент первого скрина (TabControl и всё такое) в один UserControl, контент другого — в другой. Сделайте в начале контентом окна первый UserControl, а когда нужно сменить экран — второй.

```
<UserControl x:Type="Screen1">
    <TabControl ... />
</UserControl>
```

```
class Screen1 : UserControl
{
    // ...
    void OnChangeScreenClicked()
    {
        MainApplication.Window.Content = new Screen2();
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl x:Type="Screen2">
    <!-- whatever  -->
</UserControl>
```

```
<Window ...>
    <local:Screen1 Param="Value"/>
</Window>
```

Правильнее (но сложнее) действовать через MVVM: подмените DataContext у части окна, которую нужно обновить, и пусть ContentPresenter выберет подходящий DataTemplate самостоятельно.

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourseDictionary Source="DataBindings.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- replaceable part -->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Screen}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
<!-- DataBindings.xaml -->
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type vm:StartVM}">
        <view:StartControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type vm:OtherVM}">
        <view:OtherControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="StartVM" ...>
    <TabControl...>
        ...
        <Button Command="{Binding ScreenChangeRequest}"/>
        ...
    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

ну и контроллеры:

```
class StartVM
{
    public StartVM (ICommand screenChangeRequest)
    {
        ScreenChangeRequest = screenChangeRequest;
    }

    public ICommand ScreenChangeRequest { get; private set; }
}
```

```
class MainVM
{
    // make it dependency property!
    public VM Screen { get; set; }

    private VM StartVM, OtherVM;

    public MainVM()
    {
        var screenChangeCommand = new SimpleCommand(ChangeScreen);
        StartVM = new StartVM(screenChangeCommand);
        OtherVM = new OtherVM();
        // set up initial screen
        Screen = StartVM;
    }

    void ChangeScreen()
    {
        Screen = OtherVM;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)